# bottom bar navigation not showing all titles

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following menu

```
<item android:title="@string/explore"
    android:icon="@drawable/explore"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_explore" />

<item android:title="@string/library"
    android:icon="@drawable/star"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_library" />

<item android:title="@string/upgrade"
    android:icon="@drawable/diamond"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_upgrade" />
```

For some reason, when there are three items, the titles show up. But when there are more than three items, the last title doesn't. Is it because the bottom bar is too small?

Comment: Do you have Bottom Navigation View? See my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536213/

Comment: Does it solve your problem?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to android official documentation

> The label visibility mode determines whether to show or hide labels in the navigation items

Java code:

```
setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED)
```

XML code:

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

For more details related to label visibility modes,read android documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setLabelVisibilityMode(int)