# change automatically select for bottonavigation selected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm working on this code

```
private void setupViews(){
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_id);
    bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_id);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_id,new ProfileFragment()).commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    int navID = menuItem.getItemId();
    switch (navID){
        case R.id.home:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_id,new HomeFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.search:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_id,new SearchFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_id,new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

When I launch my app, it's automatically going on first bottom (I have 3 bottoms)
I want to change this to second bottom in navigation view. Please help me

Comment: "it's automatically going on first bottom (I have 3 bottoms)"

When you say "bottom" what are you referring to? It looks like your code is trying to go the the `ProfileFragment` on startup. Is this what you want?

Comment: Where are you calling `setupViews()`?

Comment: See my answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536213/kotlin-first-item-in-bottomnavigationbar-isnt-visible-title-issues/60539233#60539233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_id);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.search);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_id,new SearchFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: thanks<3, worked by bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.search);

Answer (score 0):

@iamhanniballake

I call setupViews() in main activity 
I have 3 botoms 
-1-2-3-
when my app running open fragment with a bottomnav view
its automatically selected 3 I want to change it to 2