# First item in bottom navigation bar is not visible

Tags: java, android

First item in bottom navigation bar is not visible, although its clickable and working properly.
Tried the solutions given to this question: [KOTLIN - First item in BottomNavigationBar isn't visible, title issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60536213/kotlin-first-item-in-bottomnavigationbar-isnt-visible-title-issues)
But nothing seems to work out.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />
```

This is the code in my xml file regarding the bottom navigation bar.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <item android:title="Information"
            android:id="@+id/information_nav_bar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info" />

        <item android:title="Table"
            android:id="@+id/table_nav_bar"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_info" />
```

This is my navigation menu xml.